# Understanding Javascript parseFloat Behavior

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Note - I have read other posts on parseFloat(), but I have not found a good explanation as to why the problem occurs. (Or I just didn't understand it).

This code ...

```
var sum = parseFloat("1.001") + parseFloat(".001");

alert(parseFloat(sum));​
```

outputs ...

```
1.0019999999999998
```

I've read that adding `sum.toFixed(2)` will include only 2 decimal points.

However, I do not 100% understand why this long decimal occurs.

Does `parseFloat(sum)` represent `sum` in binary? If so, then 1.001 cannot be represented in binary since 1/2^x + ... can never equal .001 or 1/1000 exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to Javascript, but rather how [IEEE Floating Point Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) are represented internally that cause precision errors.

I won't reproduce the content here, but there are a bunch of resources available to help explain what is going on in your example.

Here is one: http://www.petebecker.com/js/js200006.html

Comment: ["What every programmer should know about floating point"](http://floating-point-gui.de/)